# Naming Convention for private const int ID property

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I'm creating this constant on a web service :

```
private const int SiteId = 4;
```

I understand that it should be Pascal Notation but resharper suggest me to use the D in capital, so the word ID is all uppercase like this :

```
private const int SiteID = 4;
```

What's the proper naming convention for this particular case ?

NOTE: Found lot of answers already on SO but none have the word ID on their examples.

Comment: It's really up to you. There is no '1 way' to format your code. Just keep it consistent and readable.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be which often-used naming conventions ReSharper follows, if any, or whether it's just JetBrains favorite? I closed as primarily opninion based for now.

Comment: Ok it get closed and -1 because it's a opinion-based answer. I'm wondering, how the hell would had known that there wasn't a naming convention for this particular case ? This ain't an opinionated answer, the answer is : There's no naming convention rule.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I don't agree with the -1 and the closing of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx

> The two abbreviations that can be used in identifiers are ID and OK. In Pascal-cased
>   identifiers they should appear as Id, and Ok.

Answer (score 4):

As Cam said, it's a matter of preference.

I prefer "Id" simply because it's an abbreviation not an acronym. You wouldn't write Site IDentification, so why write SiteID?

Perhaps this convention stems from the fact that it is usually spoken "site eye dee" as opposed to "site idd".

Comment: What is wrong with `Dentification`? - looks like some dents-making interface :)

Comment: Well I supposed if you are implementing an interface for your dentist (i.e. one who dents things).

Answer (score 0):

It's really personal preference. Personally, I like my constants to be all caps.

Comment: I agree. I carried over the all caps convention from C++. I would likely call it `SITE_ID`.

Comment: All caps with each word separated by an underscore.